# OpenGL Structure-of-Arrays Data Layout in Vertexbuffer possible?

Tags: opengl

I'm working on a CUDA/OpenGL application and my CUDA kernels achieve the best performance, when my 3D-vertex data layout is component-wise:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, .... xn, 
y1, y2, y3, y4, ..., yn, 
z1, z2, z3, z4, ..., zn
```

But, as far as I know, OpenGL prefers the vertex data in a vertex-wise format:

```
x1, y1, z1, 
x2, y2, z2, 
x3, y3, z3, 
..., 
xn, yn, zn
```

Is there a way to use the former ordering in OpenGL? It would be great If I would not be forced to transpose my data each time before and after the draw call...

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL hasn't any predefined layout, but as @NicolBolas pointed out, it has a preference for some formats. But nevertheless, the data you have can directly be passed to the shader. What you (afaik) can't do with your data is to use only one vec3 attribute. But you can use three float attributes and bind each to a different segment of the buffer.

This could, for example, look like the following:

```
//Shader
layout(location = 0) in float x;
layout(location = 1) in float y;
layout(location = 2) in float z;

void main()
{
    vec4 pos = vec4(x,y,z,1);
    ...
}


//Setup
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float) * VERTEX_COUNT));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float) * VERTEX_COUNT * 2));
```

Comment: "*OpenGL doesn't prefer any specific layout for the data.*" Considering that the layout you suggest burns 3 attributes and buffer binding points (fixed and limited resources), while the standard way only uses 1, I'd say that OpenGL does in fact have a preference.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I was looking for!
Is the "x" in the first three code lines correct? Or should it be x in the 1st, y in the 2nd and z in the 3rd?

Comment: @Catrexis: good Spot. Should be x, y, z :). I'll fix it when I'm at home.